# Rails: Nested Resources routes not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, nested-routes

I have the following routes defined:

```
resources :employees do
  resources :questions
  member do
    get :results
  end
end
```

One of the routes (rake routes) for the above resources prints this:

`new_employee_question GET  /employees/:employee_id/questions/new(.:format)  questions#new`

But when I do this `= link_to 'New Question', :new_employee_question`

I get the following error:

`No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"questions"}`

I have both `QuestionsController` & `EmployeesController` defined with the required action methods.

I also tried the following in rails console:

`Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(app.new_employee_question_path)`

...which generates the following error:

`ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:controller=>"questions"}`

I am using Rails `3.2.6`. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```
= link_to 'New Question', new_employee_question_path(@employee)
```

Comment: "rake routes" shows the path, controller#action, and route helper method name for all your routes.